# When can a declaration of an identifier that has block scope have internal linkage?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11, linkage

I was shifting around the 'C' standard and I came across this:

$6.7.9.5:

> If the declaration of an identifier has block scope, and the
>   identifier has external **or internal linkage**, the declaration shall
>   have no initializer for the identifier.

So my question is on the title. I would also like some examples if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static int i; // internal linkage

void f() {
   extern int i; // block-scope declaration; refers to i in global scope
                 // still internal linkage - see 6.2.2/4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int x = 1;

int main()
{
    int y = 2;

    {
        extern int x;

        printf( "x + y = %d\n", x + y );
    }
}
```

Here inside main in internal block variable `x` has internal linkage and denotes the same variable `x` that is defined outside main.

However in this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int x = 1;

int main()
{
    int y = 2;
    int x = 3;

    {
        extern int x;

        printf( "x + y = %d\n", x + y );
    }
}
```

the variable `x`  declared with specifier `extern` has the external linkage and it is not the same as variable `x` defined before main. The reason for this is that other local variable `x`  hides the global variable `x` that is defined before main.

Comment: Isn't that external linkage? Or maybe not because 'x' is already declared. Is this the catch here?

Comment: @FISOCPP No, it is the internal linkage because the global x is defined with keyword static.

Comment: @FISOCPP It would have external linkage if the variable x defined before main was not visible in the block where the second variable is declared with specifier extern.

Comment: OK I get it but is there a way I can declare a variable with internal linkage without the need one to be already declared.

Comment: @FOSPCPP the `static int x = 1;` is an example of that.

Comment: Isn't here static only about the storage type? When the declaration is on block-scope.

Comment: @FISOCPP Yes if the static keyword is used with a block scope variable it has the static storage duration. This word is overloaded in C.

Answer (score 0):

You should download a more recent version of the C Standard.  Look for n1570.pdf, the latest draft of the C11 Standard.  Its language is more explicit:

> **6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**
>
> 1. An identifier declared in different scopes or in the same scope more than once can be made to refer to the same object or function by a process called linkage. There are three kinds of linkage: external, internal, and none.
> 2. In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an entire program, each declaration of a particular identifier with external linkage denotes the same object or function. Within one translation unit, each declaration of an identifier with internal linkage denotes the same object or function. Each declaration of an identifier with no linkage denotes a unique entity.
> 3. If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage- class specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.
> 4. *For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.*
> 5. If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`. If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.
> 6. The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to be anything other than an object or a function; an identifier declared to be a function parameter; a block scope identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier `extern`.
> 7. If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.